# When to use std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity() vs. cmath's INFINITY

Tags: c++, stl

C++ provides both the [`std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/infinity) and the [`INFINITY` macro](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY) for representing infinity. In general, what is the difference between the two? When would one be preferable to the other?

Comment: Rule of thumb: With c++ code use c++ standard definitions.

Comment: `cmath` simply imports the c standard library functions. The `INFINITY` macro is loosely specified, the c++ limits functions are available for multiple types so are probably more applicable in c++ programs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`INFINITY` is a macro that expands to a float constant. `numeric_limits<T>::infinity` is generic, so you can use it in templates. Example:

```
template <std::floating_point F>
F foo(F number) {
    if (someCondition(number)) {
        return numeric_limits<F>::infinity();
    }
    // ...
}
```

There is no downside of using `numeric_limits<T>::infinity`, so you should always prefer that over the macro.